# How should I go about profiling Angular app initialization?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular12

The official angular documentation explains how to profile an Angular app using the DevTools https://angular.io/guide/devtools#profile-your-application

However, the DevTools are only available after the app is fully initialized, during the initialization, it just shows a loading image:

[image: DevTools during initialization]

My problem is that I have a situation where the page initialization is slow and I would like to profile that, how can I collect more information on what and which components are slowing down initialization?